# how to pass variable from a class to another class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to extract data from mongodb to Elasticsearch, `getMongodoc = coll.find().limit(10)`
 will find the first 10 entries in mongo.

As you can see ,   `result = ec.mongoConn` should get result from method `mongoConn()` in class `MongoConnector`. when I use `p hsh`(to examine the output is correct), it will print 10 entires, while  `p result = ec.mongoConn` will print `#<Enumerator: #<Mongo::Cursor:0x70284070232580 @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x70284066032180 namespace='mydatabase.mycollection' @filter={} @options={"limit"=>10}>>:each>`

I changed `p hsh` to `return hsh`,    `p result = ec.mongoConn` will get the correct result, but it just prints the first entry not all 10 entries. it seems that the value of `hsh` did not pass to `result = ec.mongoConn`  correctly, Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? is this because I did something wrong with method calling?

```
class MongoConncetor 
def mongoConn()
BSON::OrderedHash.new
client = Mongo::Client.new([ 'xx.xx.xx.xx:27017' ], :database => 'mydatabase')
coll = client[:mycollection]
getMongodoc = coll.find().limit(10)

getMongodoc.each do |document|
  hsh = symbolize_keys(document.to_hash).select { |hsh| hsh != :_id }
     return hsh
    # p hsh
end

end


class ElasticConnector < MongoConncetor
include Elasticsearch::API

CONNECTION = ::Faraday::Connection.new url: 'http://localhost:9200'

def perform_request(method, path, params, body)
puts "--> #{method.upcase} #{path} #{params} #{body}"

CONNECTION.run_request \
  method.downcase.to_sym,
  path,
  ((
  body ? MultiJson.dump(body) : nil)),
  {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
 end


 ec = ElasticConnector.new

 p result = ec.mongoConn  

 client = ElasticConnector.new
 client.bulk index: 'myindex',
               type:'test' ,
               body: result
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling return inside a loop (`each`). This will stop the loop and return the first result. Try something like:

```
getMongodoc.map do |document|
  symbolize_keys(document.to_hash).select { |hsh| hsh != :_id }
end
```

Notes:

- In ruby you usually don't need the *return* keyword as the last value is returned automatically. Usually you'd use return to prevent some code from being executed
- in ruby snake_case is used for variable and method names (as opposed to CamelCase or camelCase)
- *map* enumerates a collection (by calling the block for every item in the collection) and returns a new collection of the same size with the return values from the block.
- you don't need empty parens *()* on method definitions

UPDATE:

- The data structure returned by MongoDB is a Hash (BSON is a special kind of serialization). A Hash is a collection of keys ("_id", "response") that point to values. The difference you point out in your comment is the class of the hash key: string vs. symbol
- In your case a document in Mongo is represented as Hash, one hash per document
- If you want to return multiple documents, then an array is required. More specifically an array of hashes: `[{}, {}, ...]`
- If your target (ES) does only accept one hash at a time, then you will need to loop over the results from mongo and add them one by one:

`list_of_results = get_mongo_data
list_of_results.each do |result|
  add_result_to_es(result)
end`

Comment: Thanks, it did solve the return value problem, but when I use `map`, it will return an array  instead a hash,  the result looks like this: `[{:response=>{:version=>"1.1", :statusCode=>302,.......]`  , which could not be inserted into elastisearch, the right one should be like : `{:response=>{:version=>"1.1", :statusCode=>302,....... `  without  [ ] ,    how can I fix this?

Comment: well, it seems you want to have an array because you have multiple results? So you can either:

* use the first/last/... of the list of result: try ```.first```, ```.last``` or ```[some_index]```
* loop over the result array and insert each item into ES
* find a way to add multiple results at once to ES

Comment: actually I need a hash, maybe a hash map, cause `body:    ` in ES-ruby API only take hash as parameter,  the result I got is an array which has all 10 entries, right now I think I need find a way to make method `mongoConn` return a hash. I have 60000 entries so it may not a good idea to loop through each of them, right?

Comment: either you have one entry (a hash, which has various key/value pairs) or you have multiple entries (an array). I think there is some confusion as to what data you read from Mongo and add to ES. Perhaps you can elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: the data from Mongo is something like this : `{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('567ccbd747824a621d8b4567'), "response"=>{"version"=>"1.1", "statusCode"=>302,..........}` which is  BSON format, the data ES accept is like this : `{:response=>{:version=>"1.1", :statusCode=>302,...}`  , what I did in the code was to delete `"_id"`  and translated BSON to hash so that it could be added to ES.   At the end of the code,  ` body: result`   body parameter only take hash, while the solution you gave returns an array: `[{:response=>{:version=>"1.1", :statusCode=>302,.......} ]`

Comment: what I want to achieve is to eliminate the square bracket , thus the result could be added to ES without any error :),  am I explain it clearly enough?  do ask  if u still have any confusion, Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah, I solved it just as your suggested after I leaving those two comments,  how stupid I am - -!    sorry for the late reply!  Thank you again..

Comment: already did !  thank you ,  wondering if I can reach you by other ways? like gtalk or email